nestedScroll modifier not working as expected in compose
I was trying to achieve a lazy column with custom behavior. When the user pulls the lazy column after they reached the limits, I would show a refresh indicator by using the offset.
The problem is, when tested on API 29, it works as expected. onPostScroll reports the amount user scrolled even after reaching the top/bottom of the lazy column. However, it is not the case for API 33, which keeps reporting Offset(0.0,0.0) as if user did not scroll. How can I get the amount by which user scrolled?
Here is a snippet my code:
val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
            object : NestedScrollConnection {
                override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
                    println("PreAvailable: $available")
                    return super.onPreScroll(available, source)
                }

                override fun onPostScroll(
                    consumed: Offset,
                    available: Offset,
                    source: NestedScrollSource
                ): Offset {
                    println("PostAvailable: $available, consumed: $consumed")
                    return super.onPostScroll(consumed, available, source)
                }
            }
        }
        Box (
            modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
        ) {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp)
            ) {
                items(count = 100) {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(horizontal = 12.dp)
                            .background(Color.Blue)
                            .padding(vertical = 12.dp),
                        text = "Item $it",
                        color = Color.White,
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                    )
                }
            }
        }

